# Lodash OrderBy Alphabetical

Tags: javascript, function, lodash

I am trying to understand why the lodash orderBy function is ordering these in incorrectly. (incorrectly in my brain I suppose).

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'FLUoxetine (FLUoxetine 20 mg oral capsule)'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'ascorbic acid (Vitamin C 25 mg oral tablet, chewable)'
  }
];

const orderedData = _.orderBy(data, ["name"], ["asc"]);

console.log("DATA>>>>", orderedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The above code is logging out

```
DATAZZZZ 
[Object, Object]
0: Object
id: "1"
name: "FLUoxetine (FLUoxetine 20 mg oral capsule)"
1: Object
id: "2"
name: "ascorbic acid (Vitamin C 25 mg oral tablet, chewable)"
```

when I would think it would log out like so

```
DATAZZZZ 
[Object, Object]
0: Object
id: "2"
name: "ascorbic acid (Vitamin C 25 mg oral tablet, chewable)"
1: Object
id: "1"
name: "FLUoxetine (FLUoxetine 20 mg oral capsule)"
```

Can anyone explain as to why? I am assuming it has to do with the first 3 letters being capitalized. I read the lodash documentation, but I either missed something or do not fully understand it. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: It's not case-sensitive.

Comment: In the JS chartable, uppercase characters come before the lowercase, so `'a' < 'F' === false`, but `'A' < 'F' === true`. If you don't want to alter your object, you'll need to use your own callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowercase and uppercase letters have different codes, and the ones for uppercase come before lowercase. If you want case-insensitive sort, you can pass a formatter function to the `orderBy` as an iteratee:

```
const sortedData = _.orderBy(data, [data => data.name.toLowerCase()], ['asc']);
console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: But you specified `desc` instead of `asc`, so you'll get the same result as OP instead of their expected one..

Comment: @MarkReed my bad, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It has indeed to do with the capitalisation. I suggest using the vanilla `sort` method, where you can make your "own" rule. Moreover, it's one less library in your project! Note that this will order the current array, and not make a copy of the existing one.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'FLUoxetine (FLUoxetine 20 mg oral capsule)'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'ascorbic acid (Vitamin C 25 mg oral tablet, chewable)'
  }
];

data.sort((a, b) => {
    const textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
```